# How to convert JPG to fits in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, astropy, python-imageio

I am trying to convert a raw cr2 image into .fits using imageio and PIL. But, I am unable to convert the image into .fits format

I am currently converting .cr2 into jpg as I am unable to convert .cr2 into .fits. (if possible = best). After conversion into jpg, I am opening the file and splitting the r,g,b into 3 different arrays and pass each array to a separate .fits file but, whenever I try to pass the entire data of r,g,b combined to array it never works.

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
im = imageio.imread('E:\FYP\cr.cr2', format="RAW-FI")
imageio.imwrite(r'E:\FYP\1.jpg', im)
image = Image.open(r'E:\FYP\1.jpg')
xsize, ysize = image.size
print("Image size: {} x {}".format(xsize, ysize))
plt.imshow(image)
r, g, b = image.split()
r_data = np.array(r.getdata()) # data is now an array of length ysize*xsize
g_data = np.array(g.getdata())
b_data = np.array(b.getdata())
print(r_data.shape)
r_data = r_data.reshape(ysize, xsize)
g_data = g_data.reshape(ysize, xsize)
b_data = b_data.reshape(ysize, xsize)
red = fits.PrimaryHDU(data=r_data)
red.header['LATOBS'] = "32:11:56" # add spurious header info
red.header['LONGOBS'] = "110:56"
red.writeto(r'E:\FYP\red.fits')
```

It gives me single-colored .fits image while i want is an image with all R,G,B colors as .fits image.

Comment: You are only saving the red matrix into the FITS file: `red = fits.PrimaryHDU(data=r_data)`

Comment: FITS files store arbitrary arrays:  Images are typically intensity values of some kind (depending on the instrument) in a single color channel.  Some users might opt to create a *multi-extension* FITS file containing one 2-D array per channel, usinig the `FILTER` keyword in each header to distinguish them.  Alternatively you can output each to a single file.  Or a single 3-D array in a single extension file.  It depends on how the file is to be processed later.

Comment: As far as I can tell from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57846507/how-to-create-fits-file-from-numpy-array?noredirect=1#comment102144224_57846507) you *are* able to convert directly to a FITS file, but perhaps you are not formatting the resulting FITS file in a way understood by CCDStack.  Here is a [python script](https://github.com/eaydin/cr2fits) that converts raw CR2 images to FITS.  It requires compiling a little external C program as well.  In terms of software design it could use some work, but it does seem to do the job well.

Comment: I have created my own script but, your comments were helpful. Thanks for the suggestions.